# ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.lda'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lda

When I run `classifier.py` in the openface demos directory using:

`classifier.py train ./generated-embeddings/`

I get the following error message:

> --> from sklearn.lda import LDA
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.lda'.

I think to have correctly installed sklearn.

What could be the reason for this message?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a file named `sklearn.py` somewhere, that is shadowing the actual module?

Comment: No sklearn.py file, thank you for reply

Comment: @mauroV8F5 did my answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 26):

### It seems that you **have installed a newer version** of sklearn **but you are trying to call an old one**.

**1) First** **check your version**

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```

---

2) Then use something like the following **depending on the version** that you have installed

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
```

---

**Documentation here:**

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html

Answer (score 3):

Best guess is that you're using the call for Linear Discriminant Analysis from sklearn 0.16, not the current version (0.19).

Try using sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis instead.

Here's the [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html) to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using new version and using

from sklearn.qda import QDA

it will give error, try

from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis